# mobx is not tracking observable property

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I searched many and did everything I see that look necessary to make that obseravle stuff works but somehow mobx lack of watching observable property(menuItems).

I check execution order although fetched data loaded to field fine component renders method not re-running

```
useStrict(true);
export class AppState {
    @observable public menuItems: MenuModel[] = [];
    constructor(){
      this.setItems()
    }
    @action setItems(): void {
    fetch(`..`).then((response: { value: MenuModel[] }): void => {
        debugger
        this.menuItems = [
          { Id: 1, itemName: 'test-item1', childItems: [] }
        ];
      }, (error: any): void => {
      });
  }
```

root file;

```
const appState =  new AppState();

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider appState={appState}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Empty} />
      </Route>
   </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

app component;

```
@observer
export class App extends React.Component<{children: any, params: any}, {}> { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header className="main-header"></header>
        <main>
          <aside>
            <Menu params = {this.props.params} />
          </aside>
        </main>
      </div>
      );
    }
};
```

and Menu Component, I expect the render method below whenever observable field updated.. but it doesnt care.

```
@inject('appState')
@observer
export class Menu extends React.Component<{params?:MenuModel[], appState?: AppState}, {}> {
  render() {
    debugger
    var menuJSX : JSX.Element[] = this.props.appState ? this.props.appState.menuItems.map((item:MenuModel, i:number)=>{
      debugger
      return (<li key={item.Id}>{item.itemName}</li>)
    }):[];

    return (
        <div id="menuWrapper">
         Data: {menuJSX}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I dont know if it helps but I share how "menuItems" property looks when it comes to it, after this debugger step it goes to AppState file and set menuItems after this point execution ends, but I expect it to re-render in Menu component?
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you reproduce the problem using the pen http://codepen.io/evgeny_t/pen/ryNGBB ?